# Persisting a heterogeneous array in C#

Tags: c#, list, serialization

I have a `List<Animal>` but in that list I have subclasses of `Animal` such as `Mammal`.

I should persist it with [Serializable] interface and that is no problem, except when I shall read it back again, I have no idea what subclass the data came from when it's time for reviving the information.

So the question is, how do I store that information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to take care of that yourself, since the framework serializes the type as well it knows which instance to create before the content is actually deserialized. Just create a sample and you'll see what happens... ;-)

Comment: Same thing said a different way - the object knows what type it is; if you need to know, just ask it!  :)

Comment: Well, I am surprised. Something that works just out of the box...
Not anything that you are used to :-)

Comment: Gorgen, compared to the early days of programming, there is quite a lot which does work "out of the box" nowadays... ;)

Comment: Kind of, yes. ;) I think it's a generation question. I've been giving my first programming course (in a students-teach-students setup) some 20 years ago (which wasn't actually the early days of programming, but since I'm interested in the topic I educated myself on the topics), and since then quite a lot has changed. Man, that makes me look old I guess...

Answer (score 1):

The **is** and **as** keywords will be your friends for this.

It is good to know that the **is** keyword tries to perform a cast and returns true or false depending on whether or not the cast was successful.

If you want the actual object, and aren't just interested in its type, you are better of using the **as** keyword and then checking it for **null**.  This will save you the step of having to cast it again once you've determined the type.